# Организация исходной версии БД

Tags: база-данных, миграция, организация

Для организации структуры базы данных (и, соответственно, развертывания приложения на сервере) существуют миграции. Миграции предназначены исключительно для изменения структуры, и тот же Doctrine просто не имеет стандартных методов CRUD (первый Yii, например, имел - и, по-моему, зря), но вместе с этим зачастую требуется инициализировать приложение с некоторыми данными на борту - дефолтный админский профиль, базовые категории в блоге и т.п.

Как это правильно организовать, как это делается по-человечески? Фикстуры были бы идеальным решением (последние разы именно через них и делал), если бы не принадлежали к миру тестирования, в результате чего привязка фикстур к установке получается каким-то громадным костылем.

Comment: Меня ещё больше смущает, когда в одной репе лежат и миграции и код. 
Т.е. код мы уже выкатываем через pull, а миграции потом только применим. В это время уже сыпятся ошибки)

Comment: @Etki, не вижу ничего постыдного в инициализации базы данных SQL-скриптом.

Comment: @Nofate, постыдного там ничего нет, но вот управлять этим делом довольно геморно. Идеально - это когда есть yml-файл с массивом записей в виде `поле: значение`, и ты его правишь в любой момент без необходимости формировать эту исходную БД и дампать ее.

@dimka3210, по-хорошему должен произойти билд в соседней директории, приложение уйти в maintenance mode с заглушкой, миграции - выполниться, document root - отлинковаться от предыдущей директории и перелинковаться на нужную, после чего можно выходить из maintenance mode.

Comment: @Etki это идеальный деплой)

Answer (score 2):

Например, в рельсах есть файл `db/seeds.rb`, который исполнятеся при вызове `rake db:seed`, обычно на свежей базе -- для тестов и разработки. По идее, `rake db:seed` на продакшене вызываться не должен.

Кроме того, в миграциях не чураются писать код, вносящий какие-то значения в базу, это нормально.

Comment: Судя по всему, seeds - это то, что я называю фикстурами, данные исключительно для тестов, чтобы убедиться, что пагинация выдает пять заранее известных постов, но шестой уже прячет.

Comment: Нет, для фикстур у нас есть фикстуры. Seeds -- это то, что нужно для логики приложения.

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev, хм, почитаю об этом.